# Failed to load straight.plugin in Python 2.7

Tags: python, module, installation

I am trying to run a python script which is seems to be dependent on a module called straight.plugin, which it fails to recognise.

```
(antismash)[username@glenn antismash]$ python run_antismash.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run_antismash.py", line 32, in <module>
import straight.plugin
File "/c3se/users/username/Glenn/virtualenvs/antismash/lib/python2.7/site-packages/straight/plugin/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from straight.plugin import loaders
File "/c3se/users/username/Glenn/virtualenvs/antismash/lib/python2.7/site-packages/straight/plugin/loaders.py", line 9, in <module>
from straight.plugin.manager import PluginManager
ImportError: No module named manager
```

When I try to install straight.plugin python tells me that it is already installed.

```
(antismash)[username@glenn antismash]$ pip instal
l straight.plugin
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): straight.plugin in /c3se/users/username/Glenn/virtualenvs/antismash/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Can somebody help me on what to do to run this python script?

I am running Python 2.7.6 on Linux distribution CentOS 6.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the manager module isnt in the PyPI Package and is a known issue https://github.com/ironfroggy/straight.plugin/issues/17

Installing this version: 
`pip install straight.plugin==1.4.0-post-1` 
solves the problem for me:

`In [1]: from straight.plugin.manager import PluginManager
In [2]:`